# R date conversion to POSIX format in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api, posixct

I am trying to connect R-Impala-tableau.

I have an R code scripted in **tableau calculated field** which runs on a date field.

R code is:

```
script_str('date<- as.POSIXct(strptime(.arg1,"%m%d%y"))',attr([date_val]))
```

I want this code to run on the date values extracted from impala. 
The **date_val** here is extracted from impala and its converted to **date** type in tableau.

However, the above code returns NULL. I also tried keeping the **date_val** field to **string, date_time, numeric** data types.

I am doing this to perform a cut operation on the dates `obtained(eg:intervals<-cut(date,"1 day"))`. To do this, I need the field **date** in numeric format.

I even tried `script_str('date<- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(.arg1),"%m%d%y"))',attr([date_val]))`

Has anybody faced similar issue?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run the R specific code (`'date<- as.POSIXct(strptime(.arg1,"%m%d%y"))'`) in R itself?

Comment: Hi Talvalin. No that didnt also work. I tried that as well.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down to being an issue with the R script rather than Tableau. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Talvalin: Oops sorry. I just saw your comment carefully. You were asking whether it works in R right? Yes definitely it works in R. Only because of that I wanted it to work in tableau. My question is very specific to Tableau and NOT R. I have tried various scripts which works well in R and not in tableau. and I need help on TABLEAU only.

Comment: Please edit the question back to contain the Tableau community.